# Plot histogram of all numerical columns in pandas, with mean avxline using tight layout

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, axvline

I am trying to get all the numerical columns plotted within a tight layout with a mean line in each of the subplots for the average of each column. I have tried several options and get the following error:

```
the truth value of a series is ambiguous. use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

FYI: the code works without the plt.axvline

This is the code I have tried:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
all_col = data.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()

plt.figure(figsize=(17,75))

for i in range(len(all_col)):
    plt.subplot(18,3,i+1)
    sns.distplot(data[all_col[i]])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.title(all_col[i],fontsize=25)
    plt.axvline(data.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)#displaying the mean on the chart

plt.show()
```

Comment: please add some sample data!. I used `import seaborn as sns;
data = sns.load_dataset('tips')` to generate some.

Answer (score 2):

If I use a sample dataset, the error lies in `plt.axvline(data.mean())`, since `data.mean()` lists the means of all columns and `axvline` draws only one line at one x value.

I would do all this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset('tips')  # Sample data

num = data.select_dtypes(include=np.number)  # Get numeric columns
n = num.shape[1]  # Number of cols

fig, axes = plt.subplots(n, 1, figsize=(14/2.54, 12/2.54))  # create subplots

for ax, col in zip(axes, num):  # For each column...
    sns.distplot(num[col], ax=ax)   # Plot histogaerm
    ax.axvline(num[col].mean(), c='k')  # Plot mean
```

[image: plot]